# Problems setting up a Magento Theme

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I am simply trying to setup a Magento Theme which proves to be more difficult for me than i thought.

- I created a template (simply the definition files as per documentation and a logo.svg).
- I made my template to inherit from Luma (Magento/luma).
- My Template shows up in the themes section and i set my theme to be used in the content section.
- And then the shop suddenly looks like the Magento/blank theme...

Why is it not looking like the Luma theme although Magento correctly lists my theme as to have Luma as its parent? And why is my custom logo not displayed as it should be? So far my file structure only looks like (in app/design/frontent/Test/myTheme/)

```
composer.json
registration.php
theme.xml
web
    css
        style.css
    images
        logo.svg
```

theme.xml

```
 <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
      <title>myTheme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
      <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 </theme>
```

Also the logo should be displayed but is not.

> In the Magento application, the default format and name of a logo
>   image is logo.svg. When you put a logo.svg image in the conventional
>   location, which is /web/images directory, it is
>   automatically recognized as theme logo. It is displayed in your store
>   page header once the theme is applied.
>   (from: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Btw: Megento CE 2.2.6

The caches are flushed and the new Theme settings are applied i.e. when i switch the theme.

Comment: Looks like your theme was registered, but the .xml file ignored. Did you run recompilation? In command line go to your projects bin directory and run this: php magento setup:upgrade && php magento setup:di:compile && php magento cache:flush

Comment: Hi. Thank you but it did not help. I somehow ended up having my logo.svg displayed, but still the theme does look like the blank one instead of the luma one

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Have you check the consol?

Comment: Yes. Actually as it turns out the problem is a little bit different. It just does not inherit from luma theme. Whyever... changes i make in my theme can be deployed, however i am tweaking the blank theme instead of luma as intended.